# Base class static method returns type of subclass in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, types

I want to have a base class static method which returns an array of the subclass type. Here is my current implementation. It works, but I have a small problem with it.

```
class Animal {
    required init() { }
    public static func generateMocks<T: Animal>() -> [T] {
        var mocks: [T] = []
        // some implementation goes here...
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            mocks.append( T() )
        }
        //
        return mocks
    }
}


let myMockAnimals: [Animal] = Animal.generateMocks() // this gives me type [Animal]

class Dog: Animal {
    // dog things
    var isCute = true
}

let myMockDogs: [Dog] = Dog.generateMocks() // this gives me type [Dog]
print(myMockDogs.first?.isCute) // true

/* My problem is that it is very annoying to have to declare my
   myMockDogs variable as type "[Dog]". I would like it to
   automatically infer this type. Like this: */

let myMockDogs2 = Dog.generateMocks() // oh no! It gives me type [Animal]
print(myMockDogs2.first?.isCute) // error! Value of type 'Animal' has no member 'isCute'
if let dog = myMockDogs2.first! as Dog { // error! 'Animal' is not convertible to 'Dog';
    print(dog)
}
```

So my generic static function `generateMocks` is able to return the correct subclass when I specify the type of object I am expecting, like `let myMockDogs2: [Dog] =...`, but when I drop the explicit type I am expecting like in `let myMockDogs2 =...` then it suddenly goes back to using `Animal` as the type used for the generic function resulting in an array `[Animal]`.

**Is there a way to modify the `generateMocks` function which would cause `let myMockDogs2 = Dog.generateMocks()` to use type `Dog` for the generic `T` automatically?**

You can copy this code into a Playground too! It works there! I'm really scared there's no solution to this, but maybe a Swift genius out there has an idea.

Comment: You can't return an array of `Self` because you'd get the error: "'Self' is only available in a protocol or as the result of a method in a class; did you mean 'Animal'?" You can return just a _singular_ `Self` object, but not an _array_ of them.

Comment: @matt I’m not sure what you mean, but self in the context of a static method in Animal would likely always refer to Animal even if called by Dog statically...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is a protocol extension

```
protocol Animal {
    init()
    static func generateMocks() -> [Self]
}

extension Animal {
    static func generateMocks() -> [Self] {
        var mocks: [Self] = []
        // some implementation goes here...
        for _ in 0..<10 {
            mocks.append( Self() )
        }
        //
        return mocks
    }
}

struct Dog: Animal {
    // dog things
    var isCute = true
}

let myMockDogs = Dog.generateMocks()
print(myMockDogs.first?.isCute) // true
```

Comment: Nice! I wish it were a class, not a struct, but I've managed to make do. Thank you!